# postgres insert on conflict does not work with version 16 (at least)

Tags: postgresql, upsert

```
insert into bt(g,accountnumber,InputDate,ValueDate,Amount,Currency,Code,Reason,Branch,Type,Reference,nl1,nl2,nl3,nl4,UniqueId,Balance,UniqueIdNew)
    (select 
        0 g,
        substring(l,1,13) accountnumber,
        TO_DATE(substring(l,15,10),'YYYY/MM/DD') InputDate,
        TO_DATE(substring(l,26,10),'YYYY/MM/DD') ValueDate,
        cast(REPLACE(substring(l,37,19),',','.') as double precision) Amount,
        substring(l,57,8) Currency,
        substring(l,66,5) Code,
        substring(l,71,35) Reason,
        substring(l,107,6) Branch,
        substring(l,114,6) Type,
        substring(l,121,20) Reference,
        substring(l,142,35) nl1,
        substring(l,178,35) nl2,
        substring(l,214,35) nl3,
        substring(l,250,35) nl4,
        substring(l,286,22) UniqueId,
        cast(REPLACE(substring(l,309,19),',','.') as double precision) Balance,
        substring(l,329,353-329) UniqueIdNew
     from statement 
    )
    on conflict (accountnumber,inputdate,valuedate,amount,balance,currency,code,branch,type,reference) do nothing;
```

I had created obviously the unique index containing all above fields, and I have moreover a unique index that is named `uniqueid`.

I checked and I found that there is no entry that has the same `uniqueid` and different `(accountnumber,inputdate,valuedate,amount,balance,currency,code,branch,type,reference)` so there is no problem on that.

So the only think I can assume is that Postgres 16 has a bug and instead of checking the on conflict indexes, tries to insert the line and check later on the on conflict.

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_121286_dolibarredsce.UniqueId_UNIQUE"
DETAIL:  Key (uniqueid)=(304182960EL01P01658601) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

The code above has worked during the last 8 years and did insert correctly.
I updated Postgres to version 16 (from around 9.X) and now it gives me an error. Any ideas? Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior did not change since version 9.5, where `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` was introduced.

The `ON CONFLICT` clause will only trigger for conflicts on the unique index or constraint on the combination `(accountnumber, inputdate,valuedate, amount, balance, currency, code, branch, type, reference)`. Conflicts on `uniqueid` will trigger the exception you observe.

Since you are using `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`, the easy solution would be to just write:

```
INSERT INTO bt(...)
SELECT ...
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

If you omit the conflict target, PostgreSQL will handle any uniqueness or exclusion conflict by ignoring the new row (but you can use that only with `DO NOTHING`).

As I wrote above, it has always been like that. You probably just never hit a conflict on `uniqueid` in the past.